# Pass not working anymore : undefined symbole _ZN4llvm24DisableABIBreakingChecksE

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I had a very well working LLVM pass, but it seems to not work anymore for a very mysterious reason. I have also tried to make a basic tutorial pass work following [this](https://github.com/abenkhadra/llvm-pass-tutorial). But it gives me the same error:

```
error: unable to load plugin
  '/Clang/llvm-pass-tutorial-master/build/skeleton/libSkeletonPass.so':
  '/Clang/llvm-pass-tutorial-master/build/skeleton/libSkeletonPass.so:
  undefined symbol: _ZN4llvm24DisableABIBreakingChecksE'
```

It seems like a compatibility problem, maybe caused by an update. So, I have tried to rebuild LLVM and the pass but still got the error. Any idea on what I should do ?

Comment: Seems like a llvm C++ ABI mismatch, can you list the config of LLVM_ENABLE_ABI_BREAKING_CHECKS, or rebuilt llvm using -DLLVM_DISABLE_ABI_BREAKING_CHECKS_ENFORCING=OFF.

Comment: @ChiragPatel Where do I find the config? And if I disable it, won't it mean that I might have a run time error?

Comment: @guillau4 it's under `llvm/Config/abi-breaking.h`